# React Native - How to pass index in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a map function to create a component repetitively and dynamically. Suppose it's like this:

```
renderBoxes() {
    return Array.map(data => this.myFunction(indexOfThisArray));
}
```

How can I pass the index of the array? So that the 'myFunction' function gets the index value everytime it is called.

Comment: at least you saved my some time lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Map provides second argument as the index of the current element and third argument as the whole array itself.

```
renderBoxes() {
    return Array.map((data, index, array) => this.myFunction(index));
}
```

Read more about [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax)

Answer (score 4):

the syntax of map is

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can find the index as the 2nd parameter in the callback function

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass a second arguments to your arrow function `(data, index)`

```
renderBoxes() {
    return Array.map((data, index) => this.myFunction(indexOfThisArray));
}
```

Signaure for `.map`

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```