# Array of object iterating through map to render a component key not updating in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have two components one is the container which is calling on the item component. The container component is iterating using the map component something like this:

> ```
>     {this.state.items.map((item, id)=>{
>         return (<Car onChange={this.onChange} id={id} {...item}/>);
>
>     })}
> ```

The car component is in a Lot container as you can see but when I console.log the id in the Car component it is always coming out to be 0

```
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering "+this.props.id); 
}
```

I am missing something very trivial here and I feel really stupid for asking this question. I am using the ID to play around with data when onchange is called.

Comment: can you please show the object example of `item`, I suspect your item must have a key `id`, which is overriding the `id={id}`? Or try changing id prop to `itemId={id}` and console `this.props.itemId`.

Comment: Items starts off as an array with empty object which is [{}]

Comment: Then the behaviuor is right, second key in `map` callback is the index of item in array. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042268/react-native-how-to-pass-index-in-map-function/46042291#46042291

Comment: Try adding more than one item in array and verify it.

Comment: The problem is not with initial one the problem is with successive elements that get added

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail.?

Comment: I have an array of Car components (initially without Id) that needs to be rendered in a Lot component. I am doing that using the .map feature as you can see above. But as I am adding more cars the id of the previous cars do not get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML when you provide the same attribute multiple times, it will give preference to first only.

In JS, `map` function will provide us with three arguments in callback function, `item, index, array`.

That being said, please don't use confusing names. Consider changing your variables to this.

```
{
  this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
    <Car 
      key={`car-${index}`} 
      carIndex={index}
      car={item}  // or `data={item}`
      onChange={this.onChange} 
    />
  ))
}
```

- `key`: for uniquely identifying each instance of `Car` component.
- `itemIndex`: your logical usage
- `car`: actual item data for your component. I don't like to give my data attributes to root level of props.

Answer (score 1):

Every Component that renders to the DOM needs an unique key. Use a key attribute to identify every Car component.

```
{this.state.items.map((item, id)=>{
      return (<Car onChange={this.onChange} key={id} {...item}/>);
    })}
```

Answer (score 1):

try in this way.

`return (<Car onChange={this.onChange} {...item} key={id} id={id} />);`

May be item has unique id and it's always 0. It it will override your id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be useful

[View and edit on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7ml4kwmqwj)